Duda de suma en Js
Tengo un problema, que cuando sumo dos variables me las encadena.
let num1 = prompt("Introduzca el primer numero operable")
let num2 = prompt("Introduzca el segundo numero operable")
alert(num1 + num2)


El operador + realiza dos tipos de operaciones, una suma cuando se trabaja con enteros y una concatenación cuando se trabaja con textos. Si miras la documentación de prompt verías que devuelve textos. La solución es pasarlo a entero, por ejemplo: let num2 = parseInt(prompt..., o de cualquier otra manera. Pero vamos, que si no tienes números no sumará, si no que concatenará.

El inconveniente se origina en que la función prompt() devuelve siempre una cadena de texto, incluso si ingresas números. Para solucionarlo, es necesario convertir estos valores a números antes de operar con ellos. Puedes hacerlo mediante las funciones parseInt() o parseFloat(), que convierten la cadena a un número entero o decimal, respectivamente.
Solución:
let num1 = prompt("Introduzca el primer número operable");
let num2 = prompt("Introduzca el segundo número operable");

// Convertir las cadenas a números
num1 = parseFloat(num1);
num2 = parseFloat(num2);

// Realizar la suma
alert(num1 + num2)

También puedes hacerlo de esta manera:
let num1 = parseFloat(prompt("Introduzca el primer número operable"));
let num2 = parseFloat(prompt("Introduzca el segundo número operable"));

alert(num1 + num2);

